# DatagridCheckboxColumn with ElementStyle loses Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

When adding `ElementStyle` to a `DatagridCheckBoxColumn` and adding for example `VerticalAlignment`, the `CheckBox` loses its binding.

This code does work:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Active" Binding="{Binding Path=Active}"/>
```

And this destroys the binding:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Active" Binding="{Binding Path=Active}">
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

**How do I center the checkbox without losing binding or other functionalities?**

Answer (score 2):

By defining a custom `ElementStyle`, you are effectively overriding the default `CheckBox` style of the column. Usually, you could solve this by basing the style on the default `CheckBox` style, e.g.:

```
<Style TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}">
```

However, this **does not work**, because the `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` has its own default style with a few necessary setters that you can find in the reference source for the column [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/windows/Controls/DataGridCheckBoxColumn.cs,32).

Fortunately, the `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` exposes a static property [`DefaultElementStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridcheckboxcolumn.defaultelementstyle?view=net-5.0) that you can base your style on. The same applies to the [`EditingElementStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridcheckboxcolumn.defaulteditingelementstyle?view=net-5.0). You will want to apply both to prevent odd behavior when switching to editing mode. Here is an adapted version for both styles.

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Active" Binding="{Binding Path=Active}">
   <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
      <Style TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{x:Static DataGridCheckBoxColumn.DefaultElementStyle}">
         <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
         <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
      </Style>
   </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
   <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
      <Style TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{x:Static DataGridCheckBoxColumn.DefaultEditingElementStyle}">
         <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
         <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
      </Style>
   </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```